# "clicking" submit button with no ID using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, greasemonkey

Here is the submit button i would like to 'click' using javascript.

```
<input type="submit" name="REG_BTN" value="Submit Changes">
```

I am trying to use something along the lines of...

```
document.getElementsByTagName('submit')[0].click();
```

to 'click' the button, but it does not work. I am writing a script to run in browsers so i do not have the ability to change any of the aspects of the submit button. I am new to javascript so it may just be something simple that i am not picking up. Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `tagName` for that element is `INPUT`; there are no elements with tag name `submit`. Try this:

```
document.getElementsByName('REG_BTN')[0].click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If page is complete loading first, and use querySelector (CSS) and click.

'

```
if (document.readyState=='complete'){
  document.querySelector('input[type*="submit"]').click();
}
```

'